# d3js user of String and Math.Sqrt with no parameters

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I cannot seem to understand why is :

```
var enter = circle.enter().append("circle");

enter.attr("cy", 90);

enter.attr("cx", function(d) {
  return d;
});

enter.attr("r", function(d) {
  return Math.sqrt(d);
});
```

equal to this :

```
   svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data([32, 57, 112, 293])
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cy", 90)
    .attr("cx", String)
    .attr("r", Math.sqrt);
```

in the cx part, it is declaring a function which simply returns the input parameter d without doing anything to it. How is this then became `.attr("cx", String)` ?

Same with the `Math.sqrt`

From my limited understanding, `.data()` returns d3 objects. `.enter().attr()` are all operating on each element in the selection array with its data point.

However this syntax seem very alien to me, although I know `cx` and `Math.sqrt` get their values from the data array, I cannot seem to understand how. Also the lack of `()` in `String` and `Math.sqrt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you pass a function to the respective attribute.

In the first examples it is an anonymous function with basically no or just one function call in its body. By passing the function called inside the function body directly, you just save some space and some functions calls.